# Composing the generators of an ideal with a monic polynomial

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, function-and-relation-composition

Suppose $I = (f_{1}, \ldots, f_{n})$ is an ideal in a polynomial ring $R[x]$, where $R$ is a commutative ring with identity, minimally generated by $n$ elements.  Let $p \in R[x]$ be a monic nonconstant polynomial and define the ideal $I(p) = (f_{1}(p), \ldots, f_{n}(p))$.  Is it possible that $I(p)$ has a generating set with fewer than $n$ polynomials?

Comment: Clearly, you run into trouble if $p=1$ (sometimes considered as a monic polynomial of degree zero).

Comment: Thanks @Mohan.  I edited my question to add "nonconstant".